# How to make a fragment height take up all space left

Tags: android

I have an activity with two fragments A and B. Both have widths set to match_parent.  Fragment B has a height of 200dp and is underneath Fragment A.  I would like the height of Fragment A to fill up whatever space remains in the activity. How can I achieve this?  Any hints will be highly appreciated.

I have posted my activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:baselineAligned="false"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/image_showing_list"
      android:name="com.example.gallery.ImageShowingList"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/image_showing_list_list"
    android:name="com.example.gallery.ImageShowingList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are in a vertical `LinearLayout`, then assign `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to Fragment A.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare but I get this error message when i set android:layout_height="0dp" Suspicious size: this will make the weight invisible, probable intended for layout_width.  I have posted my activity_main.xml file for clarity.

Comment: @Jomeno: "I have posted my activity_main.xml file for clarity" -- that is not your entire `activity_main.xml` file. You can tell that because it is not a valid XML file, since there is no single root element. You will also note that my answer starts off with "If they are in a vertical `LinearLayout`. Your attributes on your fragments suggest that they are in a `RelativeLayout`, not a vertical `LinearLayout`. You may wish to post your **entire** `activity_main.xml` file, or at least the container around those two `<fragment>` elements.

Comment: I had tried using the LinearLayout without success but once I tried it again with your answer of setting android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight="1" it all worked exactly as i want.  Thank you so much, I had been on this for sometime. I give your answer a thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

make your linear layout `android:orientation="vertical"` and watch the magic happen

Comment: thanks, this was also useful. It corroborates CommonsWare's answer.